# Is it possible to run a query in Redshift that uses a variable without EXECUTE statement?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm just curious. I stumbled upon this code and wanted to get rid of `EXECUTE`. It worked for the `DROP` statement, but i couldn't figure out how do it for the `CREATE` because it's using data saved to a variable.

```
BEGIN
SELECT
    INTO row '''' + LISTAGG(DISTINCT key, ''', ''') + '''' as keys
FROM
    some_table;

EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS some_table_pivot;';

EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE DROP TABLE IF EXISTS some_table_pivot;
 AS SELECT * FROM (SELECT account_id, key, value FROM DROP TABLE IF EXISTS some_table) PIVOT (MAX(lower(value)) FOR "key" in (' || row.keys || '));';
```

does anyone know if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be the code inside a stored procedure, no?  An EXECUTE inside a stored procedure is the only way to run dynamic SQL *internally* to Redshift.

You could use some external support code to issue created SQL to Redshift.  This could be a Lambda, shell scripts, or any tool that can connect via JDBC/ODBC or API.  So just about anything.

Comment: what do you mean? Yes, it's a stored procedure, but I can remove EXECUTE from `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS some_table_pivot;` and it still runs just fine. Is dynamic SQL the one that uses variables? And the DROP statement isn't dynamic?

Comment: Correct.  That is because the entire text of the DROP SQL statement is known at the time the stored procedure is defined.  So this is just another statement in the stored procedure.  However, the CREATE TABLE statement has an unknown value at the time the procedure is created so this "new" statement must be compiled during stored procedure execution.  This is why it needs and EXECUTE statement but the DROP does not.